# How do I call a page within my Chrome Extension without using a dash?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome appears to allow users to call a page from the extension using a format similar to: \

`chrome-extension://dckobaoiekjnnheocplcnkhnhhnpjcnl/OAuth/_callback.html`

The problem is I am using Salesforce and for whatever reason they consider having a dash in the protocol invalid. The problem I am running into is I have to place a callback URL for the process I am working on. Is there another way to use https and something akin to Localhost or perhaps another protocol that does not contain a - in order to be able to call a page within my Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a call from a background page then relative path `OAuth/_callback.html` should work.

Comment: The Salesforce APP won't validate a relative path either.

Comment: Assuming you've tried `/OAuth/_callback.html`, which would also work, but maybe you require a URL with FQDN, in which case you could host the page externally to circumvent this strange limitation.